# How can I change a ClientWebPart title and description dynamically?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I have developed a ClientWebPart and now I want to change the title dynamically. Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

> How, dynamically?

I want to show users a friendly title instead of a name of the App.

I prefer to do something like this:

target.postMessage('resize(' + ($(document).width()) + ',' + ($(document).height()) + ')', '*');

But instead of **resize** I want to do **rename**.

Comment: How, dynamically? Are we talking language-wise or what?

Answer (score 1):

Since these values are written in the ClientWebPart XML node I would say no, it is not possible.

What you could possibly do is update the title of the webpart with javascript in a similiar fashion as in this  blog post: http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-6-Resizing_the_AppPart_-_ClientWebPart.aspx (but here he is changing the size of the webpart. I have not tried it but it should be possible)

Comment: I need something like this. I have noticed, that SP2013 know about the resize keyword in the postMessage. I want to do something like this:  target.postMessage('<message senderId=' + getParameterByName("SenderId") + '>rename(' + Title + ')</message>', '*');

Answer (score 0):

Could you not override the Title Property within your ClientWebPart class, putting the logic in there to change the returned string dynamically.

See ClientWebPart.Title in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.clientwebpart_members.aspx